# Is it possible to use node.js server without having the Port number appear in the URL.

Tags: node.js, apache, vps

I have a VPS using apache on port 80, but want to use node.js for a subdomain, without the port node will be using appear in the address bar.

Comment: So point the cname of that subdomain to another server (the node.js one)?

Comment: Is what you're actually asking instead "can I bind apache and node to the same port?" See https://gist.github.com/stagas/754303

Comment: That would only apply if he had more than one IP on his server.

Comment: It's name based. One IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible

In your apache virtual host file configure with the following:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.myapp.com

 ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

You should have 
NameVirtualHost *:80

Comment: Would this not run node requests through apache?